# Concatenate fields (double and string) to create address using arcpy

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, field-calculator, python-parser, error-000539

- fields:

  - STNUM = double
  - STRDIR = string
  - STRNAME = string
  - STRTYPE = string

Tuple and s.format

I have tried:

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management (newparcelsUTM, "SiteAddress","{0} {1} {2} {3} ".format('!STRNUM!','!STRDIR!','!STRNAME!','!STRTYPE!'),"PYTHON_9.3")
## set variable- str(double) ##
```

I have tried setting a variable to change the double field to a string:

```
AddNum = str('!STNUM!')
```

then use it in the Calculate field line:

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management (newparcelsUTM, "SiteAddress", AddNum+" "+'!STRDIR!'+" "+'!STRNAME!'+" "+'!STRTYPE!'),"PYTHON_9.3")
```

All my attempts end with:

> ExecuteError: ERROR 000539: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (, line 1)
>   Failed to execute (CalculateField).

I have tried different iterations on this- single quotes v double quotes... it works if I use just the STNUM field. It works if I use any combination of the string fields. It just does not work combining the double field with the string fields! I have read many threads regarding concatenate, Field calculator, combine double with string, on stack exchange and the Esri sites... I have been trying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need quotes around the field names. `format()` will convert everything to strings for you so you don't have to do any conversions. For fields with NULLs, use `!FIELD! or ""` so it doesn't put a `None` in the address.

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(
    newparcelsUTM, 
    "SiteAddress",
    '"{0} {1} {2} {3}".format(!STRNUM!, !STRDIR! or "", !STRNAME!, !STRTYPE!)',
     "PYTHON_9.3" 
)
```

Comment: when I remove the single quotes and try to run the script, then I get a new dialogue box that pops up with 'There's an error in your program: invalid syntax' and the first exclamation point on STRNUM is highlighted red.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to put the expression in quotes, see update

Comment: Those can be a pain - you should be able to get around it with an `or ""` to swap it with an empty string (see update)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the da.UpdateCursor:

```
import arcpy
fc = r'C:\data.gdb\featureclass' #Change
fields = ['SiteAdress','STNUM','STRDIR','STRNAME','STRTYPE']
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = ' '.join([i for i in row[1:] if i is not None]) 
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Thanks BERA- I forgot to mention that there are NULLs in some of the fields, so for some of them I get a return of 619 None Englebert Way... I am not fond of cursors- because of my lack of understanding!- but Marc's answer worked.

Comment: I have changed the code so it will work with nones

Comment: @Gross, cursors are much cleaner, more versatile, and more "pythonic". I recommend learning them.